# Pandas df.to_html is not displaying links correctly

Tags: hyperlink

I have being trying to display an entire df as html with hyperlinks that are clickable.  However whenever I use df.to_html it always displays the link as the plain text and not a hyperlink.  See below

I am using pandas v 2.2.1

Does anyone have a way around this?

Here is some code to reconstruct the issue:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import random
from IPython.display import display, HTML

# Generate 10 random names
names = \[random.choice(\['John', 'Jane', 'Jim', 'Jill'\]) for i in range(10)\]

# Create empty DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=\['Name', 'Link'\])

# Populate DataFrame with names and hyperlinks
for name in names:
    link = f'<a href="https://example.com/{name}">{name}</a>'
    df.loc\[len(df)\] = \[name, link\]

# write out the whole frame to HTML
display(HTML(df.to_html()))

# test that my display is working properly
mylink = '<a href="https://example.com/Jim">Jim</a>'
display(HTML(mylink))

# trywrite out a single column row value
display(HTML(df.loc\[1, 'Link'\]))
```

This is what I get for the first write:

```
    Name    Link
0   Jim <a href="https://example.com/Jim">Jim</a>
1   Jim <a href="https://example.com/Jim">Jim</a>
2   John    <a href="https://example.com/John">John</a>
3   Jane    <a href="https://example.com/Jane">Jane</a>
4   Jane    <a href="https://example.com/Jane">Jane</a>
5   John    <a href="https://example.com/John">John</a>
6   Jane    <a href="https://example.com/Jane">Jane</a>
7   Jane    <a href="https://example.com/Jane">Jane</a>
8   Jill    <a href="https://example.com/Jill">Jill</a>
9   Jim <a href="https://example.com/Jim">Jim</a>
```

Let last 2 display links as expected.